# Can dockerfile comments be in foreign languages?

Tags: localization, comments, dockerfile

I am translating documentation for non-English users learning Docker. We have some example Dockerfiles with comments which we would like to translate for better understanding by the students. Are non-English languages, specifically Japanese, allowed in Dockerfile comments? If the students copy/paste the comments or try to type their own in a non-English language, will that create a problem?